# Avoiding nested try...finally blocks in Delphi

Tags: delphi, interface, try-catch

I had this idea this morning on avoiding nested try finally blocks like the following

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  T1, T2, T3 : TTestObject;
begin
  T1 := TTestObject.Create('One');
  try
    T2 := TTestObject.Create('Two');
    try
      T3 := TTestObject.Create('Three');
      try
        //A bunch of code;
      finally
        T3.Free;
      end;
    finally
      T2.Free;
    end;
  finally
    T1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

By taking advantage of the automated reference counting of interfaces, I have come up with

```
Type  
  IDoFinally = interface
    procedure DoFree(O : TObject);
  end;

  TDoFinally = class(TInterfacedObject, IDoFinally)
  private
    FreeObjectList : TObjectList;
  public
    procedure DoFree(O : TObject);
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

//...

procedure TDoFinally.DoFree(O : TObject);
begin
  FreeObjectList.Add(O);
end;

constructor TDoFinally.Create;
begin
  FreeObjectList := TObjectList.Create(True);
end;

destructor TDoFinally.Destroy;
begin
  FreeObjectList.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

So that the previous block of code becomes

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  T1, T2, T3 : TTestObject;
  DoFinally : IDoFinally;
begin
  DoFinally := TDoFinally.Create;
  T1 := TTestObject.Create('One');
  DoFinally.DoFree(T1);
  T2 := TTestObject.Create('Two');
  DoFinally.DoFree(T2);
  T3 := TTestObject.Create('Three');
  DoFinally.DoFree(T3);
  // A Bunch of code;
end;
```

My question is: does this work or have I overlooked something?

To me this looks pretty cool, and makes the code a bit easier to read with the reduced amount of nesting.  It could also be extended to store a list of anonymous methods to run to do things such as close files, queries, etc...

Comment: I honestly do not like this method. It actually makes the code *less* readable. Sure, it minimizes the amount of code you have to read, but you're only complicating things.

Comment: The compiler will put a hidden try-finally block in to ensure that the interface is decremented (and freed).

Comment: That's correct, @Nicholas. Was that ever in question?

Comment: @JerryDodge I think whenever you stray from "standard" Delphi coding practices you can make code harder to understand (for anyone but the author) - even if it is simpler.  See Rob Kennedy's answer using the JCL - it is even shorter and cleaner.  My goal is more to remove all the extra stuff so that the Business Logic is easy to follow.

Comment: Well it's a huge matter of developer preference. I generally tend to stick with as lowest level as possible (besides WinAPI and ASM)

Comment: Also don't forget that `Add()` will raise an exception if there is a problem with memory, so you would have to use a `try/except` block to ensure untracked objects still get freed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Yes, it works.**

Perhaps the only thing different between the nested try-finally blocks of the original code and the technique of using a reference-counted object to manage the lifetimes of other objects is what happens if there's a problem destroying any of the objects. If there's an exception while any object is being destroyed, the nested try-finally blocks will ensure that any remaining objects will still get freed. The `TObjectList` in your `TDoFinally` doesn't do that; if any item in the list can't be destroyed, any subsequent items in the list will be leaked.

In practice, that's not really a problem, though. No destructor should ever throw an exception. If it does, there's not really any way to recover from it anyway, so it doesn't matter if anything leaks because of it. Your program should terminate momentarily anyway, so having a tidy cleanup routine is of little importance.

Incidentally, the JCL already offers the `ISafeGuard` and [`IMultiSafeGuard`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help%3aIMultiSafeGuard) interfaces for managing local objects' lifetimes. For example, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
uses JclSysUtils;

procedure DoSomething;
var
  T1, T2, T3: TTestObject;
  G: IMultiSafeGuard;
begin
  T1 := TTestObject(Guard(TTestObject.Create('One'), G));
  T2 := TTestObject(Guard(TTestObject.Create('Two'), G));
  T3 := TTestObject(Guard(TTestObject.Create('Three'), G));
  // A Bunch of code;
end;
```

That library doesn't address exceptions in destructors, either.

Comment: In my continued playing I've changed DoFree to a function returning the TObject - so that the one liner above is possible.

Comment: +1 This answer clearly states the potential issue of the original code which may occur if a destructor raise an exception.

Comment: +1 for "No destructor should ever throw an exception. If it does, there's not really any way to recover from it anyway, so it doesn't matter if anything leaks because of it."

Answer (score 14):

I usually do something like this, as provides a balance between code readability and complexity:

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  T1, T2, T3 : TTestObject;
begin
  T1 := nil;
  T2 := nil;
  T3 := nil;
  try
    T1 := TTestObject.Create('One');
    T2 := TTestObject.Create('Two');
    T3 := TTestObject.Create('Three');

    // A bunch of code

  finally
    T3.Free;
    T2.Free;
    T1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

### Warning:

- This is not completely equivalent to your original code, because if `T3.Free` throws an exception, `T2` and `T1` will not get freed and cause a memory leak, and the same for `T2.Free` in respect of `T1`.
- However, as *Rob Kennedy* points in his comment, and explain in more detail in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18497396/859646), it is equivalent to your alternative code using `IDoFinally`.
- So your two approaches are not completely equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I've used this technique.  If your destructors are throwing exceptions then you are probably doing something seriously wrong.  Infact I cover this technique in a video I made a few years ago- http://learndelphi.tv/index.php?option=com_content&id=58

Comment: It's equivalent to the code that uses `IDoFinally`. It's not equivalent to the code with the nested try-finally blocks.

Comment: I frequently use this technique, but I would put `T1 :=  TestObject.Create('One')` before the try, but after the nil assignments

Comment: As stated, this code is unsafe if something goes wrong in the destructor. Never code like that!

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez if you are frequently getting exceptions in destructors, something is wrong somewhere

Comment: There is one fundamental problem here, the .Create calls should precede the try finally block as the destructor is automatically called upon constructor exception...

Comment: @whosrdaddy There's no problem at all. When the scenario you describe occurs, the object reference, e.g. `T1`, is not assigned. And thus `T1.Free` is a no-op.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez For example: `TPdfArray.Destroy`, `TPdfDictionaryElement.Destroy`, `TPdfDictionary.Destroy`, `TPdfStream.Destroy`, `TPdfXref.Destroy` and so on. What's more, anytime you override a destructor and the inherited destructor calls `Free`, then you are in the exact same situation. Your complaint is unjustified.

Answer (score 8):

[Smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) are other way to achieve automatic memory management.

The *[ADUG](http://members.adug.org.au/)* website has an Delphi [implementation](http://members.adug.org.au/2011/12/05/smart-pointers/) derived from *[Barry Kelly's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3712/barry-kelly)* articles on how to implement strongly-typed smart pointers in Delphi using generics, anonymous methods and interfaces:

1. [Smart pointers in Delphi](http://blog.barrkel.com/2008/09/smart-pointers-in-delphi.html)
2. [Reference-counted pointers, revisited](http://blog.barrkel.com/2008/11/reference-counted-pointers-revisited.html)
3. [Somewhat more efficient smart pointers](http://blog.barrkel.com/2008/11/somewhat-more-efficient-smart-pointers.html)

Your code will be rewritten as this:

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  T1, T2, T3 : ISmartPointer<TTestObject>;
begin
  T1 := TSmartPointer<TTestObject>.Create(TTestObject.Create('One'));
  T2 := TSmartPointer<TTestObject>.Create(TTestObject.Create('Two'));
  T3 := TSmartPointer<TTestObject>.Create(TTestObject.Create('Three'));

  // A bunch of code
end;
```

Comment: +1 this was what immediately popped into my mind, but couldn't find it soon enough.

Answer (score 8):

I have a set of helper functions to make @JRL's approach more digestible.

```
procedure InitialiseNil(var Obj1); overload;
procedure InitialiseNil(var Obj1, Obj2); overload;
procedure InitialiseNil(var Obj1, Obj2, Obj3); overload;

procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj1); overload;
procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj1, Obj2); overload;
procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj1, Obj2, Obj3); overload;
```

In fact my code has versions with even more parameters. For ease of maintenance this code is all automatically generated from a short Python script.

These methods are implemented in the obvious way, e.g.

```
procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj1, Obj2);
var
  Temp1, Temp2: TObject;
begin
  Temp1 := TObject(Obj1);
  Temp2 := TObject(Obj2);
  Pointer(Obj1) := nil;
  Pointer(Obj2) := nil;
  Temp1.Free;
  Temp2.Free;
end;
```

This allows us to re-write the code in the question like this:

```
InitialiseNil(T1, T2, T3);
try
  T1 := TTestObject.Create('One');
  T2 := TTestObject.Create('Two');
  T3 := TTestObject.Create('Three');
finally
  FreeAndNil(T3, T2, T1);
end;
```

And the Python script:

```py
count = 8


def VarList(count, prefix):
    s = ""
    for i in range(count):
        if i != 0:
            s = s + ", "
        s = s + prefix + str(i + 1)
    return s


def InitialiseNilIntf(count):
    print("procedure InitialiseNil(var " + VarList(count, "Obj") + "); overload;")


def FreeAndNilIntf(count):
    print("procedure FreeAndNil(var " + VarList(count, "Obj") + "); overload;")


def InitialiseNilImpl(count):
    print("procedure InitialiseNil(var " + VarList(count, "Obj") + ");")
    print("begin")
    for i in range(count):
        print("  Pointer(Obj%s) := nil;" % str(i + 1))
    print("end;")
    print()


def FreeAndNilImpl(count):
    print("procedure FreeAndNil(var " + VarList(count, "Obj") + ");")
    print("var")
    print("  " + VarList(count, "Temp") + ": TObject;")
    print("begin")
    for i in range(count):
        print("  Temp%s := TObject(Obj%s);" % (str(i + 1), str(i + 1)))
    for i in range(count):
        print("  Pointer(Obj%s) := nil;" % str(i + 1))
    for i in range(count):
        print("  Temp%s.Free;" % str(i + 1))
    print("end;")
    print()


for i in range(count):
    InitialiseNilIntf(i + 1)
print()
for i in range(count):
    FreeAndNilIntf(i + 1)
print()
for i in range(count):
    InitialiseNilImpl(i + 1)
print()
for i in range(count):
    FreeAndNilImpl(i + 1)
```

Comment: could you post the entire Python script output on pastebin or whatever?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative I sometimes use:

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  T1, T2, T3: TTestObject;
begin
  T1 := nil;
  T2 := nil;
  T3 := nil;
  try
    T1 := TTestObject.Create;
    T2 := TTestObject.Create;
    T3 := TTestObject.Create;
    // ...
  finally
    T1.Free;
    T2.Free;
    T3.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Same code as JR, but with no explication nor warning. As stated there, this code is unsafe if something goes wrong in the destructor. Never code like that!

Comment: @Arnaud The concern about exceptions in destructors is misplaced. In code that everyone write are destructors whose implementation is just a list of calls to Free. Nobody worries about the issue there. So why get up-tight here?

Comment: Same problem as @JRL's solution: The .Create calls should precede the try finally block as the destructor is automatically called upon constructor exception

Comment: @whosrdaddy There's no problem at all. When the scenario you describe occurs, the object reference, e.g. T1, is not assigned. And thus T1.Free is a no-op.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Did you see such code in the VCL? nested `try..finally` blocks is the proper/classic/safe way. This code mimics the behavior emitted by the compiler for local interface variables (which will be initialized with `nil` at method entering, and create one `try..finally` block). But compiler generated code is  safe, whereas you can easily forget to write something by hand, whereas `try..finally` are easy to insert from the IDE editor, and much easier to work with when your code grows and you want to refactor it in smaller methods.

Comment: It's all over the VCL in destructors. It's all over your code too. And indeed everyone writes code that leaks when a destructor raises. On a personal level, I'm happy with try/finally and don't see a problem in need of a solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was talking about the `... := nil; ... := nil; try .. finally ...Free; ...Free; end` pattern in the code, not the execution trace which is quite common (this is why I spoke about `interface`). Such code is hard to refactor, and error prone e.g. if you do not take a look at the compiler hints and forget to initialize one variable to `nil`.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Your initial comment was not discussing that. That's what I want to talk about!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed, the concern about exceptions in destructors is misplaced, I agree. But the fact that this code pattern is not to be followed could be argued.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Yes, I'm with you there. Once the nesting depth reaches three or four, none of the options are particularly compelling.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this code works, although I would personally be inclined to add `inherited` to your constructor and destructor.

There are many libraries out there that have implementations that use this mechanism. The latest Delphi compilers for mobile platforms manage object lifetimes using ARC, automated reference counting, which is the same technique but baked into the compiler's treatment of object references.

Comment: Oops, you are correct - I've added inherited to the destructor.  I don't know that it is required on the constructor is it?

Comment: You can omit it, but why would you do so?

Comment: I've been told we are not going to see ARC for the VCL, but I think we will be seeing it for FireMonkey on the desktop - which would be cool.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different implementation of the same idea:

```
unit ObjectGuard;

interface

type
  TObjectReference = ^TObject;

  { TObjectGuard }
  TObjectGuard = class(TInterfacedObject)
  private
    fUsed: integer;
    fObjectVariable: array [0..9] of TObjectReference;
  public
    constructor Create(var v0); overload;
    constructor Create(var v0, v1); overload;
// add overloaded constructors for 3,4,5... variables
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TObjectGuard.Create(var v0);
begin
  fObjectVariable[0] := @TObject(v0);
  Tobject(v0) := nil;
  fUsed := 1;
end;

constructor TObjectGuard.Create(var v0, v1);
begin
  fObjectVariable[0] := @TObject(v0);
  Tobject(v0) := nil;
  fObjectVariable[1] := @TObject(v1);
  Tobject(v1) := nil;
  fUsed := 2;
end;

destructor TObjectGuard.Destroy;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to FUsed - 1 do
    if Assigned(fObjectVariable[i]^) then
    begin
      fObjectVariable[i]^.Free;
      fObjectVariable[i]^ := nil;
    end;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

The advantage being the simple usage, such as:

```
procedure Test;
var
  Guard: IInterface
  vStringList: TStringList;
  vForm: TForm;
begin
  Guard := TObjectGuard.Create(vStringList, vForm);
  vStringList := TStringList.Create;
  vForm:= TForm.Create(nil);
  // code that does something
end;
```

It's convenient that you can create the Guard at the beginning of the method and pass any number of Variables in one call. So you don't have to first create object instances.

Also notice the variables will automatically be initialised to nil in the Constructor.

Edit:
Also, due to the fact that interface lifetime is equal to the execution time of the method, we can use that for profiling, perhaps IFDEF-ed for easier control.

Comment: Could you have a constructor that takes an array of objects?  This is an interesting solution that I will have to play with.

Comment: I don't think you can use an array in the same way here. I just have 9 overloaded constructors, but I never really have more than 4-5 object variables in a method

Comment: I've played around with this and changed it to use a FreeList : TList<TObjectReference>;. And added a Fluent Add method - function TObjectGuard.add(var v) : TObjectGuard;.  So that you can do- Guard := TObjectGuard.Create.Add(T1).Add(T2).Add(T3);

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to wrap the destructor in an interface. By default, Delphi builds a behind-the-scene try/finally into each procedure/function that uses interfaces, in which the reference count of the interfaces are decreased, thus calling the destructor when it reaches zero.

I had a quick check, but (at least in Delphi 7) an exception in one destructor will stop the other destructors, sadly enough. One way to stop this is write try/except's in each destructor, but this is again more code somewhere else just to save on code in the first place...

```
type
  IMyIntf=interface(IInterface)
    function GetName:string;
    procedure SetName(const Name:string);
    property Name:string read GetName write SetName;
  end;

  TMyObj=class(TInterfacedObject, IMyIntf)
  private
    FName:string;
    function GetName:string;
    procedure SetName(const Name:string);
  public
    constructor Create(const Name:string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x,y:IMyIntf;
begin
  x:=TMyObj.Create('a');
  y:=TMyObj.Create('b');

  x.Name:='x';
  y.Name:='y';
end;

{ TMyObj }

constructor TMyObj.Create(const Name: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FName:=Name;
end;

destructor TMyObj.Destroy;
begin
  MessageBox(Application.Handle,PChar(FName),'test',MB_OK);
  //test: raise Exception.Create('Destructor '+FName);
  inherited;
end;

function TMyObj.GetName: string;
begin
  Result:=FName;
end;

procedure TMyObj.SetName(const Name: string);
begin
  FName:=Name;
end;
```

Comment: FWIW, desktop window should not be used as a dialog owner

Comment: oops, during the years of debugging, I've grown a custom of doing `MessageBox(GetDesktopWindow,,,MB_OK or MB_SYSTEMMODAL)` to be sure it would show in all cases. I forgot the systemmodal, but apparently still use GetDesktopWindow. If I remember correctly, one could pass 0 just as well.

Comment: It's a bad idea. Raymond Chen has covered this.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to understand which method to use based on the end purpose, but in some cases, this is where I tend to implement subroutines, or in general separate my code into different functions. For example...

```
FOne: TSomeObject;
FTwo: TSomeObject;
FThree: TSomeObject;

....

procedure DoSomething;
begin
  FOne:= TSomeObject.Create;
  try
    //a bunch of code which only needs FOne
    DoSomethingElse;
  finally
    FOne.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure DoSomethingElse;
begin
  FTwo:= TSomeObject.Create;
  try
    ShowMessage(DoYetAnother);
    //A bunch of code that requires FTwo
  finally
    FTwo.Free;
  end;
end;

function DoYetAnother: String;
begin
  FThree:= TSomeObject.Create;
  try
    //Do something with FOne, FTwo, and FThree
    Result:= FOne.Something + FTwo.Something + FThree.Something;
  finally
    FThree.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Again, it's difficult for you to understand how this would work without a more real-life scenario. I'm still thinking for a good example and will gladly edit when I think of one. The general idea though is separating different segments of business rule into different re-usable blocks of code.

Alternatively, rather than declaring global variables, you could also pass parameters from one procedure to the next.

Comment: I like this point of view (though I hesitate to use word "like" on StackOverflow anymore :-) Usually (not always, of course), if one is working with a certain object (create, do something, and free), it is due to a certain reason which can be named. And if can be named, it can be wrapped to a method (or procedure) in my opinion.

Comment: I usually tend to work with no more than 2 (two!) interacting objects at the time. If I have to use third object, I'm usually isolating code to the subroutines (locals are good too). This rule effectively reduces ugliness of nested blocks to the acceptable minimum.