# OOP equivalent for a goto chain for releasing resources upon error?

Tags: oop, delphi, memory-management, exception

In C I've used goto chains for releasing resources upon error, as recommended [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM12-C.+Consider+using+a+goto+chain+when+leaving+a+function+on+error+when+using+and+releasing+resources). Working with Delphi I've encountered the following situation where I want to gracefully handle memory exhaustion and also prevent memory leaks:

```
New(A);
A.DoSomething;
New(A.B);
A.B.DoSomething;
New(A.C);
A.C.DoSomething;
```

As I understand it the way to check for memory exhaustion is by catching an exception thrown by `New`. Let's say the `DoSomething` functions all throw `Exception` on error. SEI CERT's coding standard recommends against [in-band error checking](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/ERR52-J.+Avoid+in-band+error+indicators) and against [using exceptions for control flow](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/ERR50-J.+Use+exceptions+only+for+exceptional+conditions), at least for Java, which I find very reasonable. I'm unsure how to deal with this situation keeping these recommendations in mind. My idea was to do something like

```
function AllocStuff : TA;
begin
  New(Result);
  Result.B := nil;
  Result.C := nil;    
  Result.DoSomething;    
  New(Result.B);
  Result.B.DoSomething;
  New(Result.C);
  Result.C.DoSomething;
end;
```

Catching exceptions on the caller:

```
procedure QuestionableControlFlow;
var
  A : TA;
begin
  A := nil;
  try
    A := AllocStuff;
    DoSomethingWith(A);
    Dispose(A);
  except on E : Exception do
    begin
      if (A <> nil) then
        begin
          if (A.B <> nil) then
            begin
              if (A.C <> nil)  then
                begin
                  Dispose(A.C);
                end;
              Dispose(A.B);
            end;
          Dispose(A);                    
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Is this as bad as it looks? Mixing `goto` with `except` seemed worse and this was all I could think of so far.

Comment: `goto` is generally considered evil, it should rarely be used, if ever. For C++, the better solution is to use RAII instead, and then create objects on the stack and let their destructors release resources as the objects go out of scope. C and Delphi do not have RAII, or stack-based objects with destructors, though. In Delphi, you can simulate RAII using interfaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Delphi you use `try/finally` for unmanaged resource lifetime.

For instance

```
obj := TObject.Create;
try
  obj.DoSomething;
finally
  obj.Free;
end;
```

You absolutely don't use `try/except` for this, although that is a common mistake. That's for handling exceptions which is different from guaranteeing finalisation.

When you need to deal with multiple unmanaged resources in one function you can nest your `try/finally` blocks. When the nesting is deep that can be messy. Some ideas for dealing with that can be found here: [Avoiding nested try...finally blocks in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497085/avoiding-nested-try-finally-blocks-in-delphi)

Comment: If I could add +10 to this answer, I would! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your `AllocStuff()` should use `try/except` to catch errors, so it doesn't return invalid data:

```
function AllocStuff : TA;
begin
  New(Result);
  try
    Result.B := nil;
    Result.C := nil;    
    Result.DoSomething;    
    New(Result.B);
    try
      Result.B.DoSomething;
      New(Result.C);
      try
        Result.C.DoSomething;
      except
        Dispose(Result.C);
        raise;
      end;
    except
      Dispose(Result.B);
      raise;
    end;
  except
    Dispose(Result);
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

And then the caller can use `try/finally` to release whatever `AllocStuff()` returns:

```
procedure QuestionableControlFlow;
var
  A : TA;
begin
  A := AllocStuff;
  try
    DoSomethingWith(A);
  finally
    Dispose(A.C);
    Dispose(A.B);
    Dispose(A);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Nested members should be disposed by the main type, in its Destroy method. Manual Dispose() is buggy as hell (even if it works, properly coded), and breaks the simplest benefits of encapsulation. As David wrote in his answer, just define properly the object and its nested members, then use it protecting the resource with a try/finally.

Comment: @Arnaud, you're right about an encapsulation, but for the question example, this answer correctly considers exception in allocator (constructor) and properly releases nested allocated resources. For such case you just cannot use `try..finally` as the nested members must stay allocated when the allocator returns.

Comment: @Victoria Asker thinks goto is valid for this so I wouldn't get hung up on the techniques shown in the Q.