# confusing Inheritance using RTTI

Tags: class, delphi

pardon me if the question is not as per the rules but due to curiosity I just want to know why my objects `classtype` is making me confuse.

please see the below code:

```
 type 
 TFirstClass = class
 end;

  TSecondClass = class(TFirstClass)
  end;

  TThirdClass = Class(TSecondClass)
  End;
```

the above is my class structure.

In one method I just want to check class type of the class object.

```
    var
      obj1: TFirstClass;
      obj2: TSecondClass;
      obj3 : TThirdClass;
      str: string;
    begin
      obj1 := TSecondClass.Create;
      obj2 := TThirdClass.Create;
      try
    if obj1 is TFirstClass then
        str  := str + ' obj1: first ||';

    if obj1 is TSecondClass then
        str  := str + 'obj1 : Second ||';

    if obj2 is TSecondClass then
        str  := str + 'obj2 : Second ||';

    if obj2 is TThirdClass then
        str  := str + 'obj2 : Third ||';

    ShowMessage(str);
   finally
        FreeandNil(Obj1);
        FreeandNil(Obj2);
      end;

    end;
```

but the result in **str** is
**obj1: first ||obj1 : Second ||obj2 : Second ||obj2 : Third ||**

Why `is` keyword returning true for all `if` statement?

Comment: OT: Your try-finally is incorrect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497085/avoiding-nested-try-finally-blocks-in-delphi or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_References) has the answer:

> The is operator, which performs dynamic type checking, is used to verify the actual runtime class of an object. The expression:
>
> ```
> object is class
> ```
>
> returns True if object is an instance of the class denoted by class or one of its descendants, and False otherwise.

They key phrase is "or one of its descendants".

Answer (score 5):

`TThirdClass` derives from `TSecondClass`, which derives from `TFirstClass`.  As such:

- `obj1` is just a `TFirstClass` by itself.
- `obj2` is a `TSecondClass` WHICH IS ALSO a `TFirstClass`.
- `obj3` (had you instantiated it) is a `TThirdClass` WHICH IS ALSO a `TSecondClass` WHICH IS ALSO a `TFirstClass`.

The `is` operator looks at the entire inheritance hierarchy, and returns True if the requested class type is found. If you want to do exact class matches, you need to compare the class types directly, eg:

```pascal
if obj1.ClassType = TFirstClass then
  ...

if obj1.ClassType = TSecondClass then
  ...

if obj2.ClassType = TSecondClass then
  ...

if obj2.ClassType = TThirdClass then
  ...
```